# Messages not sending on MacBook Pro

Tags: messages, messages-in-icloud

When using ichat or iMessage on my MacBook Pro, suddenly a couple of contacts are not receiving my texts. Also, I don't get a notification as to the status of the text, whether it has or has not been delivered. Other contacts still receive my messages. They all have iPhones. I have tried turning the app off and restarting it but to no avail. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried signing in and out of iMessage?

Comment: Sorry, I meant sign out of iMessage then sign in again